# Backbone view that render child views of the same type causes endless loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a category model that has child category models (That works fine) via this code:

```
var ImageSetCategory = Backbone.Model.extend({

        childrenCategories : new Array(),

        initialize: function () {
            var self = this;

            if (this.has('childrenCategories')) {

                $.each(this.get('childrenCategories'), function () {

                    var category = new ImageSetCategory(this);

                    self.childrenCategories.push(category);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I also have a view that uses this model and renders all the children categories. (basicly, I'm attempting to make a tree view) It loops through the child categories using jquery, instantiates a new version of its self with each child category as the model, and renders it. But I'm hitting an endless loop that constantly is trying to process the same model.

```
var ImageSetCategoryView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: 'li',

        className: 'nested-category',

        template: Handlebars.templates.imageSetCategoryView,

        render: function() {
            var self = this;

            var templateHtml = this.template(this.model.toJSON());

            self.$el.html(templateHtml);

            // *****************************
            // ENDLESS LOOP
            //   this is always the same model from the array
            // *****************************
            $.each(self.model.childrenCategories, function () {
                var categoryView = new ImageSetCategoryView({ model: this });

                self.$el.children('ul').append(categoryView.render().el);
            });

            return this;
        },
    });
```

Why is this causing an endless loop? Am I'm not following best practices? My background is C# so I'm trying to accomplish this in an OOP way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that all instances of `ImageSetCategory` share the same `childrenCategories` array. This way in `ImageSetCategory.initialize` function you create circular references (`ImageSetCategory.childrenCategories` points to the array and `ImageSetCategory.childrenCategories[0]` points to `ImageSetCategory` itself). This makes `$.each` in `ImageSetCategoryView.render` iterate over the same model. To avoid it you should initialize array inside of `ImageSetCategory.initialize` function:

```
var ImageSetCategory = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        var self = this;

        this.childrenCategories = [];

        if (this.has('childrenCategories')) {

            $.each(this.get('childrenCategories'), function () {

                var category = new ImageSetCategory(this);

                self.childrenCategories.push(category);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

To learn more about why this happens read about prototypes in JavaScript and how they are used to implement object-oriented paradigm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have just started learning about prototypes. I didn't realize that extending a backbone type via the object literal actually assigns them to the prototype.

Comment: I found this:

http://www.erichynds.com/blog/backbone-and-inheritance

That explains what you just said